Openai Status Webhook Autocancel
I have integrated Openai Api in my application, but occasionally the service is not available. So I want to stay informed about service availability by subscribing to the Openai Status Webhook.
But I often get the following notification in my email:
Webhook problem detected
We've detected a problem with your webhook endpoint subscribed to the OpenAI status page, so we've deactivated the webhook.
Please make sure that your webhook endpoint of https://*****.com/openai-status-webhook is responding with a 2xx response code within 30 seconds of the initial connection. initial connection.
As mentioned here my webhook is not responding with a 2xx status code, but my service logs and multiple tests are responding with a 200 status code, and I even added the 200 part to the response body:
return jsonify({'code': 200, 'message': 'Success'}), 200
Is anyone else experiencing this issue please? Now I have to manually re-subscribe after every cancel, defeating the purpose of doing this.

